# Why is Darkgrey brighter than normal grey?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass, vscode-extensions

I think there might be no answer to it but why is the preset color darkgrey brighter thant the normal grey preset? (Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is DarkGray lighter than Gray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811973/why-is-darkgray-lighter-than-gray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically I see where you are coming from, it makes sense to add the word "dark" in front of a color to indicate that it is a darker shade of said color. Look at these three colors as you can see "HTML Gray" is a more darker shade then "HTML DarkGray" but when we look at "HTML LightGray" and its rgb values we see that it is a light version of both "HTML Gray" and "HTML Dark Gray". For Dark Gray it is being compared to Light Gray. And when you look at just those two colors that is how the names are being derived from. At the end of the day they are just names we give for different shades of colors.

-HTML Gray:
HEX: #808080
RGB: rgb(128,128,128)

-HTML DarkGray:
HEX: #A9A9A9
RGB: rgb(169,169,169)

-HTML LightGray:
HEX: #D3D3D3
RGB: rgb(211,211,211)

link for you convince:https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_shades.asp